# Result of SQL Query in PHP not Formatting in JSON

Tags: php, sql, json, wamp

I have a PHP script which works to display JSON data based on the SQL query. The database is stored in my WAMP server so I updated this table in PHPMyAdmin to include a 'E_Description' column and inserted some sentences. I then restarted all services in wamp manager. However, when I add 'E_Description' into the Select clause of the query and run the script it returns a blank screen. I tried changing the type of 'E_Description' from TEXT to VARCHAR and neither make a difference. I also tried a new script to simply return the descriptions and this didn't work either.

Here's the PHP script that works:

```
$query = "SELECT Event_ID, Title, Category, Zone, Start_Date, End_Date FROM UM_Events" 
or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 

//execute the query. 
$result = $link->query($query); 
//display information: 

foreach ($result as $row){
$return['events'][]=array('event_id'=>$row['Event_ID'],'title'=>$row['Title'], 
'category'=>$row['Category'],'zone'=>$row['Zone'],'start_date'=>$row['Start_Date'], 
'end_date'=>$row['End_Date']);
}
$query = null;

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

The code that doesn't work:

```
$query = "SELECT Event_ID, Title, Category, Zone, Start_Date, End_Date, 
E_Description FROM UM_Events" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 

//execute the query. 

$result = $link->query($query); 

//display information: 

foreach ($result as $row){
$return['events'][]=array('event_id'=>$row['Event_ID'],'title'=>$row['Title'], 
'category'=>$row['Category'],
'zone'=>$row['Zone'],'start_date'=>$row['Start_Date'], 'end_date'=>$row['End_Date'],
 'e_description'=>$row['E_Description']);
}
$query = null;

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

Thank you

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: try `var_dump($result);` just after `$result = $link->query($query);` and see what is inside.. other thing is believe you could do something like `json_encode($result);` and it also should work, as the `$result` should be an kind of array itself. But first determine whether the query returns correct data.

Comment: You should check to see that your query is returning values with mysqli error check, and output a response if it fails.

Comment: Mary, need to know what the statement `$result = $link->query($query);` does, as it looks like you are issueing a query but not getting the results before trying to process the results. What MYSQL Extension are you using MYSQL_* or MYSQLI_* or PDO?

Comment: I'm using PDO for this. '$link' sets up the connection to the database like this: $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ulstermuseum_schema") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); I tried var_dump($result) and everything came back as null. Does anyone know why the query wouldn't return values?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this already do the job? Guessing that $link is a mysqli object here.

```
$query = "SELECT Event_ID, Title, Category, Zone, Start_Date, End_Date, E_Description FROM UM_Events");

$result = $link->fetch_assoc($link->query($query));

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```